# Passing quarkus.hibernate-orm.proc.param_null_passing" - dont work : Call Stored Procedure

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, quarkus

Thanks a lot for the opportunity..

I will try to pass 2 parameters in my Quarkus rest code, using Hibernate call stored Procedure at oracle database.

Unfortunatily when I try to call the Oracle procedure, I receive this error:

[io.qua.config] (Quarkus Main Thread) Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.hibernate-orm.proc.param_null_passing" was provided;

---

````
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:106)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:372)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:218)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:519)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:73)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:138)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler$1.run(VertxRequestHandler.java:93)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$13.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:536)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2442)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1476)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The parameter at position [7] was null. You need to call ParameterRegistration#enablePassingNulls(true) in order to pass null parameters.```
----------------------------
>> Follow my code:

>StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("{ ? = call mypackage.myprocedure(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)} ");
>        query.setHint("quarkus.hibernate-orm.proc.param_null_passing", true);

> query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, Integer.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
>       query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, Long.class, ParameterMode.IN);
>       query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(3, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
>       query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(4, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
>       query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(5, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
>       query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(6, Long.class, ParameterMode.IN);
>       query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(7, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
>       query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(8, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
>       query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(9, String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
>       query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(10, String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
        
>       query.setParameter(2, x);
>       query.setParameter(3, xx);
>       query.setParameter(4, xxxx);
>       query.setParameter(5, ccccc);
>       query.setParameter(6, sssss);
>       query.setParameter(7, null);    
>       query.setParameter(8, null);

Thanks a lot for the response and help.
````

Comment: The error message is `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The parameter at position [7] was null. You need to call ParameterRegistration#enablePassingNulls(true) in order to pass null parameters.` Have you tried calling `ParameterRegistration#enablePassingNulls(true)`?

Comment: Thanks for response. Yes. Follow my application.properties quarkus.hibernate-orm.proc.param_null_passing=true ---- I already tried to put this code too: ----------------query.setHint("quarkus.hibernate-orm.proc.param_null_passing", true);

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot use `quarkus.hibernate-orm.proc.param_null_passing` as a query hint.

You can set the property `hibernate.proc.param_null_passing` globally for hibernate. Quarkus doesn't let you set this directly (in you `application.properties`) you would have to do it with a `persistence.xml`. As noted in the [quarkus hibernate docs](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm) however, you cannot mix and match the two - if you already have any `hibernate-orm` properties in `application.properties` you'll have to move them over to `persistence.xml`

Something like this for example (which I've not tested)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="MyPersistenceUnit" >
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.proc.param_null_passing" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

You can use query hints to handle this though. You must set it for each parameter, for example a query hint `query.setHint("hibernate.proc.param_null_passing.7", true)`. If you are using named instead of indexed parameters, you could set swap out `7` for the name instead.

It is worth noting, that according the hibernate documentation, this is all deprecated  and will be handled implicitly (since hibernate 5.3), but I've not had any luck with that actually work - I use query hints with named parameters.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I will annotate this recomendation.